# Office add-in Excel VSTO office 365 (desktop) support

Tags: excel, vsto

Do you know if this is possible to create a VSTO add-in for excel in an office 365 suite (on desktop, of course)? 
Officially, it says it is supported.

But, if I create an empty project on VisualStudio with the default "Office 2013 & 2016 VSTO add-in", it does not load. 
But, it works on other machines, with excel 2016.

Can you help me with this?

I already tried many things. And, it seems that the add-in does not even show in the list of COM add-ins in the setup menu. It's not disabled; and, if I look at the registry, the load behavior is 3.

The only strange thing that I found is that when I try to link manually the .dll file using the "add-in" menu, it says that the dll is not a valid excel add-in. 
But, if I do it another way and click to the .vsto file, the explorer says that the add-in has been installed correctly..

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think you're after the Web Addin written in JavaScript

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office

Comment: Could you provide more information, please, on what you mean by "Office 365" vs. "Excel 2016" - just so we're sure we're looking at the same thing. Also, have you activated `Show add-in user interface errors` in File/Options/Advanced, the General section? That will display any problems there might be in a Ribbon in the add-in, which could be why you're not seeing it where/when you expect to. Also, make sure *all* the code is in try...catch blocks otherwise some Office-generated errors won't bubble up to a .NET project.